# Taking the derivative of a function of a convex combination of vectors, $f((1-t)x + t\cdot y)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $f$ be a differentiable function, $x\not = y$ and vectors (say in $\mathbb{R}^n)$, and define $g:(0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
g(t) = f((1-t)x + t\cdot y)
$$
How would I differentiate this with respect to $t$. That is, what is $g'(t)$

I believe I need to take the total derivative of it with respect to $t$, which would give me something like
$$ \tag{3}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial [(1-t)x + t\cdot y]}\cdot \frac{ \partial [(1-t)x + t\cdot y]}{\partial t} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}
$$

Now I can re-write 
$$
\frac{ \partial [(1-t)x + t\cdot y]}{\partial t} = -x\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} +y\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}
$$
But I don't know what to do with those partials (I don't know if I need them or not... I don't know for sure if $x,y$ depend on $t$... they probably don't, though) or the $\frac{\partial f}{\partial [(1-t)x + t\cdot y]}$ term...

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice not to use the kind of writing you do use. For example, to my point of view, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial ((1-t)x+ty)}$ does not make any sense.

Here is a way to compute your derivative, with the chain rule formula. Let $h(t)=(1-t).x+t.y$. Then $g=f\circ h$ so

$$g'(t)=f'(h(t)).h'(t)=f'((1-t).x+t.y).(y-x)$$